# Empty entries inserted with PDO, bindparam fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert a form with some values into the MySQL db using PDO.

```
    /*** Values for the form ***/
    $date = date_create();
    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $uid = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
    $admin = 1;

    /*** prepare the SQL statement ***/
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (message_id, timestamp, uid, admin, read, edited, message) VALUES ('',':time',':uid',':admin','','',':message')");

    /*** bind the paramaters ***/
    $stmt->bindParam(':time', $time, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':admin', $admin, PDO::PARAM_INT, 1);
    $stmt->bindParam(':message', $message, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
    $stmt->execute();
```

The result is:
an empty entry with only the message_id set and message still with it's placeholder :mesagge

```
(message_id, timestamp, uid, admin, read, edited, message)    
15 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |:bericht
```

What is wrong with the placeholders or INSERT query?

Comment: You don't need to quote the parameters in your SQL - `:time` is what you need. `':time'` passes a string containing `:time` to the database as the value, rather than creating a placeholder

Comment: @andrewsi Why don't you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (message_id, timestamp, uid, admin, read, edited, message) VALUES ('',':time',':uid',':admin','','',':message')");
```

When you're using placeholders, you don't need to quote them. When you have `':time'` in your SQL, it's passing a string with the text `:time` to the database. Your SQL should look like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (message_id, timestamp, uid, admin, read, edited, message) VALUES ('',:time,:uid,:admin,'','',:message)");
```

(Edit, based on IMSoP's comment)

You also don't necessarily need to have fields in your INSERT, if there's no data being added. If a column is missing, the row will be added using the default value for that column, based on the table's design; or NULL if there isn't one. If it's an AUTO_INCREMENT field, then it shouldn't be in your INSERT statement, as it's going to cause issues. You can't use this on fields that are set to NOT NULL, and it's important to remember that NULL and `''` are different values, so using this will depend on how you've written the rest of the code; but you can get away with code as short as:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (timestamp, uid, admin, message) VALUES (:time,:uid,:admin,:message)");
```

Comment: Inserting `''`, inserting `NULL`, and omitting the column in the statement are *not* equivalent. Firstly, `''` and `NULL` are different values; secondly, omitting the column will use the column's `DEFAULT` value, if one has been specified, and only fall back to `NULL` if not (and the column allows `NULL`s). In Postgres, an auto-increment field is technically just one which has a `DEFAULT` pulling the next number from a `SEQUENCE`, which is why omitting that column is generally desired. I agree with your suggestion, but it's important to know what it will actually do.